# Vertical line in Tradingview with pine script

Tags: pine-script

The follwing script should display a vertical line but it doesn't work. I cannot see the line.

```
//@version=4
study("Vertical Line Tabname", overlay=true) // Add overlay=true parameter to make the script draw on the original chart
fromTime = timestamp(2023, 5, 10, 21, 0, 0) // Calculate the timestamp for February 10th of the starting year
line.new(fromTime, 80, time, 120, color=color.blue, width=2, extend=extend.none) // Draw a vertical line at the calculated timestamp with a reduced extend parameter
```

I tried different variants of the script, zoomend in and out in chart. By the way I used
the Amazon chart and the current share price is 110$. The vertical line should be drawn from 80 to 120$.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `time` as your `x` argument. In that case, you should also use `xloc=xloc.bar_time`.

```
line.new(fromTime, 80, time, 120, xloc=xloc.bar_time, color=color.blue, width=2, extend=extend.none)
```

**Note:** Since you are drawing the lines without any conditions, it will draw bunch of lines from the selected time/bar.